# How to move most cms content from mediawiki to django-cms?

Tags: content-management-system, mediawiki, django-cms, cms-migration

I'm planning to move a site from mediawiki to django-cms. It has around 150 pages and a similar number of embedded images.

The question is how to do it with minimal effort. There are several issues:

- django-cms does not support mw wiki sintax, should I export html?
- how can I dump all the the wiki pages as plain html
- how to automate the process or at least minimize the effort.
- how to deal with internal links (there are not so many internal links, probably under 2/page)
- how to deal with images

Comment: Please specify why you want to do this - that will help us provide an answer.

Comment: I think the reasons are not important but mainly because mediawiki has serious issues with multilanguage websites, navigation and URLs All these are very well managed by django-cms. Don't get me wrong, I love mediawiki and I think it is probably the best wiki.

Comment: Thanks for that, Sorin. I do not know what issues you have with those features because I thought they all work well (e.g. all URLs are unique and predictable). Glad you like MediaWiki, though! =:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reaction - do it manually. 150 pages is not much and you can certainly do it in one working day (probably less) - which is about the same time it will take you to find and test an automated solution.

I've moved a wiki to another format and found I got a long way with just find and replace in Notepad!